# Unexplained jquery span hide() & show() behaviour

Tags: jquery, hide, show, html

I have some strange behaviour which I have found a workround for but would like to understand what is happening.

Web Site: Using ASP(V4); JQuery(1.7.1); Firefox (10.0.2);

On page have two labels :

```
<asp:Label ID="errsOnlyResult" runat="server" Text="<p>errsOnlyResult" ></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="fullCodeResult" runat="server" Text="<p>fullCodeResult" ></asp:Label>
```

The server side code behind will assign text to both of these labels.

Page has a checkbox which I want to use to toggle which of these labels is displayed.
ie:
 When checked want label ID="errsOnlyResult" displayed, ID="fullCodeResult" hidden
 When cleared want label ID="fullCodeResult" displayed, ID="errsOnlyResult" hidden

Toggling is done via jquery handler on the checkbox: Code to do toggle:

```
function applyShowErrOnlyCBox() {
    var checked = $("input[id$='ShowErrOnlyCBox']").is(':checked');

    if (checked) {
        console.log("JQuery ShowErrOnlyCBox click event: Checked");
        $("span[id$='errsOnlyResult']").show();
        $("span[id$='fullCodeResult']").hide();
    }
    else {
        console.log("JQuery ShowErrOnlyCBox click event: unchecked");
        $("span[id$='fullCodeResult']").show();            
        $("span[id$='errsOnlyResult']").hide();
    }
}
```

Using firebug to step thru this jquery code it is executing as expected.

Problem is that both labels are shown or both are hidden. I have found that both will follow the hide/show behaviour of which ever is defined first in the page layout. Its as if the style from the first is propagating on to the second.

Remember that asp:label is rendered as a span.

ie relevant part of page renders as:

```
  <span id="MainContent_errsOnlyResult"><p>errsOnlyResult</span>
  <span id="MainContent_fullCodeResult"><p>fullCodeResult</span>
```

Using firebug to step thru the jquery libs I see what happens. When the hide()/show() is applied to the first span the rendered page changes for both span's. The order in which the functions are executed does not matter. Its the order in which they are defined that defines which style settings are used.

I worked round the problem by putting the labels (spans) in different 's

ie when labels defined as:

```
<div>
<asp:Label ID="errsOnlyResult" runat="server" Text="<p>errsOnlyResult" ></asp:Label> 
</div>

<div>
<asp:Label ID="fullCodeResult" runat="server" Text="<p>fullCodeResult" ></asp:Label>
</div>
```

it works as expected.

I experimented with adding further asp:labels (spans) in the same  and the behaviour seems consistient.

It would seem that all 's within a  takes the sytle of the first span in the

Is this the expected behaviour or have I misunderstood something here.
Not urgent as I have found a work round - but interested to understand why I need different 's

Thanks in advance for any replys.

Phil.

Comment: Are you closing the paragraph tags (in the label text) in the real code, or is the above a copy/paste?  If you break the DOM structure then you can expect unusual results.

Comment: To debug the problem I am not updaing the label in code behind. The labels render as the span's shown above.

Comment: In that case, make sure you close the paragraph tags as it is currently invalid.  That can cause issues in itself, and the issues could be different from browser to browser.  At least make sure you fix it to rule it out.

Answer (score 0):

The answer with thanks to Archer:

The text assigned to the labels does not have paragraph terminator tags.

While I understand this may be valid html it is not valid xml ie the DOM doc is not valid.  The JQuery library gets confused about where the end of the element is. I guess the div work round added clarity for JQuery.

code for solution:

replace:

```
<asp:Label ID="errsOnlyResult" runat="server" Text="<p>errsOnlyResult" ></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="fullCodeResult" runat="server" Text="<p>fullCodeResult" ></asp:Label>
```

with

```
<asp:Label ID="errsOnlyResult" runat="server" Text="<p>errsOnlyResult</p>" ></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="fullCodeResult" runat="server" Text="<p>fullCodeResult</p>" ></asp:Label>
```